# Bootstrap Sass change fonts folder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel with default bootstrap sass, but I'm a little confused about the fonts being copied to a folder diferente the one I've set on the variables file.

My current setup

```
// app.scss
@import "variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

// variables.scss
$icon-font-path: "../fonts/bootstrap/";

// webpack.mix
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/bootstrap.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/bootstrap.css')
```

I was expecting to see a `font\bootstrap` but instead I've a `fonts\vendor\bootstrap-sass\bootstrap`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the icon font path

```
$icon-font-path: "/fonts/bootstrap/";
```

Comment: That's embarrassing, I was thinking the path was relative to the public/css.
Thanks.